# $\ell^1$ functor as left adjoint to unit ball functor

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory

In a comment to this answer

https://mathoverflow.net/a/38755/1106

Yemon Choi notes that "The $\ell^1$ functor is the free Banach space functor, left adjoint to the forgetful unit ball functor".

This statement is intriguing to me, but I am not quite sure what categories and functors Yemon is talking about here.  I imagine that we have the category of Banach spaces (with which maps?) on one side, but what about the other?  If anyone can fill in the details here I would be very pleased.  Also, if anyone has references to a functional analysis text which takes this perspective, I would be happy with that answer as well.

Comment: Since the question is tagged as a reference request, I should mention the article by Pumplün and Röhrl: [Banach Spaces and Totally Convex Spaces I](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927878408823035?journalCode=lagb20)

Answer (score 6):

You want to take the category $\text{Ban}_1$ of Banach spaces and [short maps](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/short+map) (linear maps of operator norm $\le 1$). The unit ball functor $U : \text{Ban}_1 \to \text{Set}$ is represented by $\mathbb{C}$, and its left adjoint sends a set $S$ to the coproduct of $S$ copies of $\mathbb{C}$, which turns out to be $\ell^1(S)$. This says that we have a natural bijection

$$\text{Hom}_{\text{Ban}_1}(\ell^1(S), B) \cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Set}}(S, U(B))$$

which says that a map from a set $S$ to the unit ball $U(B)$ of a Banach space extends uniquely and freely to a short map $\ell^1(S) \to B$, by "linearity."

Intuitively speaking this says that $\ell^1(S)$ is obtained from $S$ by requiring that each element of $S$ have norm $1$ (so that it's in the unit ball and can map shortly to any other element of any other unit ball) and then asking that a linear combination $\sum c_s s$ have the largest possible norm compatible with this (so that it can map shortly to any other such linear combination in any other Banach space). We have $ \| \sum c_s s \|  \le \sum |c_s|$ by the triangle inequality and the $\ell^1$ norm is the equality case of this.

This construction generalizes to the construction of the coproduct in $\text{Ban}_1$, which looks like this: if $B_i$ is a collection of Banach spaces, their coproduct in $\text{Ban}_1$ is the completion of the vector space direct sum $\bigoplus_i B_i$ with respect to the "$\ell^1$ norm" $\sum_i \| b_i \|_{B_i}$.

Apologies for the self-promotion, but I go into a bit more detail about categorical properties of $\text{Ban}_1$ (e.g. it is complete, cocomplete, and closed symmetric monoidal) in my blog post *[Banach spaces (and Lawvere metrics, and closed categories)](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/banach-spaces-and-lawvere-metrics-and-closed-categories/)*. In particular I attempt to motivate the use of short maps. Note that if we only work with bounded linear maps then we can't hope to recover a Banach space up to isometry via a universal property, whereas the isomorphisms in $\text{Ban}_1$ are isometric. On the other hand the categorical language is still capable of talking about bounded maps, via the closed structure.

Comment: I used to get bothered by the fact that one often had to do ad hoc scaling tricks in constructions that would "naturally" be done using addition of morphisms in ${\rm Ban}_1$, but I guess your final comment says that this can and should be done using the closed structure -- would that be a fair interpretation?

Comment: @Yemon: I'm not sure. We can talk about the entire Banach space of bounded maps, but singling out a particular bounded map (of norm $> 1$) requires talking about the "obvious" forgetful functor to $\text{Set}$ (not the unit ball functor); you don't actually get a morphism in the category so you can't use this sort of thing to e.g. reduce the computation of (co)equalizers to (co)kernels. It is a bit unsatisfying to have to divide by $2$ or whatever but on the other hand it's also pretty harmless.

Comment: My misgivings about dividing by 2 were mainly aesthetic, since "taking the mean of two things" is not associative :) And yes I think it was in some place where I wanted to define or prove things about pullbacks where this annoyance arose

Answer (score 4):

Let Bang (Ban, geometric) denote the category whose objects are Banach spaces and whose morphisms are the linear maps that have norm $\leq 1$. (We can work over either real or complex scalars.) Let Set be the category whose objects are sets and whose morphisms are functions.$\newcommand{\Ball}{{\sf ball}}$

There is a functor $\Ball$ from Bang to Set which assigns to each Banach space its closed unit ball; the condition on the morphisms of Bang ensures that each $f:X\to Y$ in Bang restricts to a function $\Ball(X) \to \Ball(Y)$.

What would a left adjoint to $\Ball$ look like? We can use the description/characterization in terms of initial objects in comma categories. So for each set $S$ we want a Banach space $F(S)$ and a function $\eta_S: S \to\Ball(F(S))$ with the following universal property: whenever $E$ is a Banach space and $h:S\to \Ball(E)$ is a function, there is a unique Bang-morphism $T: F(S)\to \Ball(E)$ such that $\Ball(T)\circ\eta_S=f$ as functions.

Unravelling the definitions of the various morphisms: what we require is that for any function $h$ from $S$ to $E$ satisfying $\Vert h(j)\Vert \leq 1$ for all $j\in S$, there should be a unique linear map $T: F(S) \to E$ such that $\Vert T(v)\Vert \leq \Vert v\Vert$ for all $v\in F(S)$ and $T(\eta_S(j))=h(j)$ for all $j\in S$.

Having tried to motivate things, let's make the *Ansatz*. Define $F(S)$ to be the Banach space $\ell_1(S)$ with its usual norm $\Vert\quad\Vert_1$; let $(e_j)_{j\in S}$ denote the canonical basis bectors in $\ell_1(S)$. The only possible candidate for the linear map $T:\ell_1(S) \to E$ is: define $T(e_j):= h(j)$ for each $j$, and extend by linearity and continuity. To see that this works, observe that for any $v=\sum_{j\in S} \lambda_j e_j \in \ell_1(S)$ we have

$$
\Vert \sum_{j\in S} \lambda_j h(j) \Vert \leq \sum_{j\in S} \vert \lambda_j \vert \Vert h(j)\Vert \leq 
\sum_{j\in S} \vert \lambda_j \vert  \sup_{j\in S} \Vert h(j)\Vert \leq \Vert v \vert_1
$$

Summing up: essentially what the argument above says is that a bounded linear map from $\ell_1(S)$ to a Banach space $E$ defines a bounded function $S\to E$, and that conversely every bounded function $S\to E$ has a unique bounded-linear extension $\ell_1(S)\to E$. (Note that this paragraph, which is stated in analyst language rather than categorist language,is a little more general because I'm not requiring everything to have norm $\leq 1$; but restricting to Bang seems essential if one wants to get a nice statement of this analysis-fact in the language of adjunctions.)

Actually we can go further and say that the adjunction isomorphism $Set(S, \Ball(E)) \cong {\rm Bang}(\ell_1(S),E)$, which a priori is just a naturally-behaving bijection of sets, can be enriched to an isomorphism in Bang: $\ell_\infty(S;E) \cong {\mathcal B}(\ell_1(S),E)$.

Comment: While I was writing this rambling account, I think Qiaochu said it more concisely and coherently

Comment: We could the last paragraph as follows: consider the category of bornological sets with bounded maps as morphisms, and view $S$ as a bornological space with the bornology being all subsets. Then $S\to\ell^1(S)$ seems to be the initial map from the bornological set $S$ to a Banach space.

Comment: I suspect that there is a further generalization. Note that $\ell^1(S)$ is the space of signed measures on $S$. We know another analogue: when $S$ is a compact Hausdorff space, the map $S\to\mathcal M(S)$ to the Banach space of Radon measures with the canonical norm is initial among all maps to a Banach space, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Z.M Initial in what sense? i.e. what is the category that you are comparing with Ban? I would not be surprised if there is a generalization, but I wrote my answer to answer the particular question that was asked, not to attempt some kind of encyclopaedia of similar results.

Comment: @Z.M If you are seeking to use $M(S)$ as some kind of left adjoint, then my instinct is that you need to be using its structure as a dual space (or if you like a certain POV, Waelbroeck space / Smith space) and not just its normed structure. This is why I am not sure what you mean precisely by "initial among all maps"

Comment: "Initial among all maps from $S$ to a Banach space" means to be the initial object in the slice category of Banach spaces $E$ along with a bounded map $S\to E$, which is just rephrasing the adjunction. And yes, $\mathcal M(S)$ is naturally a Smith space at least when $S$ is profinite, but I tend to believe that the norm topology is its "Banachification".

Comment: @Z.M I am not fluent in all this condensed stuff but I have been thinking categorically about Banach spaces for 10-15 years, so perhaps we are just talking about the same thing in different language. So what you are saying is that we should consider a category BornSet, and then $\ell^1$ is the left adjoint to the "unit ball functor" from Bang to BornSet?

Comment: I still don't understand what precisely you are claiming about the space of Radon measures. So now you are working with the category of compact Hausdorff spaces and continuous maps, and you want to make M(S) into a functor from this category to Bang which is a left adjoint? But the unit ball of M(S) is not compact in the norm topology, which is the only topology that can be seen in Bang. This is why I assumed that you were actually talking about a functor from CompHaus to Wael

Comment: Maybe I was mistaken about the compact Hausdorff spaces. For sets $S$, I was just rephrasing your last equivalence (not enriched, but just the underlying sets): the left hand side $\ell^\infty$ is precisely the collection of bounded maps $S\to E$, i.e., the Hom-set in the category of bornological spaces. So $\ell^1$ is at least a "partial left adjoint" to the forgetful functor from Banach spaces to bornological sets, defined on those coming from sets $S$. I suspect the the left adjoint exists, and thus it coincides with $\ell^1$ when restricting to these $S$ coming from sets...

Comment: (cont'd) and that is why I was trying to think of compact Hausdorff spaces, since these are another instances which give rise to (natural) bornological sets. In addition, to clarify, unit balls no longer appear, and I think of the category of Banach spaces with morphisms being continuous linear maps, not just of norm $\le1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is **Exercise 20**, on *page 167* in **Lectures and Exercises on Functional Analysis** by *Helemskii*.

A more ample discussion is carried out by *Jiří Rosický* in **[Are Banach spaces monadic?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.07543)**, arXiv:**2011.07543**.

Comment: I thought Rosicky's paper was about the adjunction between some-category-like Ban and some-category-like Met? (Arens-Eells spaces IIRC)

Comment: The non-monadicity of the adjunction between $\ell_1$ and ${\rm ball}$ is, I think, due to Linton, but I might by misremembering.

Comment: @YemonChoi you are right, but Jiri gives references and puts context around the question, that is why I call it "a more ample discussion". His style is dry, but the ref. list is quite rich.